# Scaling the height of a div with CSS

Tags: html, css, resize, height, scale

I have a div on my page but when I resize my window then the height gets weird. With an image I would do this:

```
heigt: auto;
```

How can you do it for a div?

Thanks!

ps. i  have this:

```
<body>
   <div id="divworks">
      <img src="image.png">
   </div>
   <div id="mydiv">
   </div>
    <div id="divworks1">
      <img src="image.png">
    </div>
</body>

#mydiv {
   margin-top: 80%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 115%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: #424242;
   padding-bottom: 1%;
   }
```

Comment: What does "gets weird" mean? What height are you trying to achieve? Please posts your HTML snippet and improve your question.

Comment: Also you are using the same Id more than once...that's invalid HTML.

Answer (score -1):

`height:auto;` lets your browser determine the height of the div which is why it scales when you change the size of your browser.

If youl want to set the height use `height:100px;` or whatever number of pixels you need.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Will explain some other options you can go with if you need more options.